# pushViewController takes time to navigate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have two ViewControllers. In my first ViewController there is a button from which I navigate to second ViewController.

In second ViewController there is a `UITableView` and it's cell only. I use storyboard for designing. This cells are not static cells and I reusing this cells.

**My problem is when I run application in iPhone 4s (iOS 9.3.5) and navigate to second ViewController from first ViewController, application freezes for some seconds and then navigate to second ViewController.**

This same code runs perfectly fine in iPhone 5 and higher versions of iPhone. I am using following code for navigation

```
SecondViewController *secondController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyIdSecondController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:TRUE];
```

Comment: Have you call any API in second view? You can use dispatch method for navigation.

Comment: No, I not called any api

Comment: try to put  `pushViewController` in main queue

Comment: @MikeAlter - I done that too, but no any effect

Comment: is your tableview cell have images in it ? or its a simple tableview ?

Comment: no, it don't have any image, it's a simple uitableview which has 5 prototype cell. This cells used for creating form which takes data from user

Comment: Remove all codes from viewdidLoad of second view controller (if any) and keep them in viewdidApear. And then check.